# Cmd.exe changes font all of a sudden

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, fonts

I made a config installer with different installation prompts. For one prompt, the cmd.exe font changes after choosing a specific option (Option [2] here). I have no idea why that happens. Someone else used the installer too and their cmd.exe's font didn't change.

Here's an example of the changed font: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZGJuikVvwM

This is the code for the prompt:

```
:localization
cls
set "fz="
set "localization01="
set "localization02="
set "localization03="
set "localization04="
del /f /q "config\_temp\installed.fz" 2>nul
findstr /i /r /c:"FANTAZIA localization files have been installed successfully." "%apb%\APBGame\Localization\GER\EULA.GER" >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    set "localization01=[92m(+)[0m"
    @break > "config\_temp\installed.fz"
)
findstr /i /r /c:". colorized weapon names and categories.*\(\+\).*" "%apb%\APBGame\Localization\GER\EULA.GER" >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    set "localization02=disable colorized weapon names and categories"
    @break > "config\_temp\installed.fz"
) else (
    set "localization02=enable colorized weapon names and categories"
)
findstr /i /r /c:". rainbow colored text in player inspect windows.*\(\+\).*" "%apb%\APBGame\Localization\GER\EULA.GER" >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    set "localization03=disable rainbow colored text in player inspect windows"
    @break > "config\_temp\installed.fz"
) else (
    set "localization03=enable rainbow colored text in player inspect windows"
)
findstr /i /r /c:". fantazia related localization changes.*\(\+\).*" "%apb%\APBGame\Localization\GER\EULA.GER" >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    set "localization04=disable fantazia related localization changes"
    @break > "config\_temp\installed.fz"
) else (
    set "localization04=enable fantazia related localization changes"
)
if exist "config\_temp\installed.fz" (
    xcopy /s /y /q "config\APBGame\Movies" "%apb%\APBGame\Movies" >nul
    xcopy /s /y /q "config\APBGame\Splash" "%apb%\APBGame\Splash" >nul
) else (
    xcopy /s /y /q "config\_backup\APBGame\Movies" "%apb%\APBGame\Movies" >nul
    xcopy /s /y /q "config\_backup\APBGame\Splash" "%apb%\APBGame\Splash" >nul
)
echo note: localization variations [2], [3] and [4] are togglable.
echo.
echo [2] install localization files %localization01%
echo.
echo [2] %localization02%
echo.
echo [3] %localization03%
echo.
echo [4] %localization04%
echo.
echo [5] create shortcut
echo.
echo [C] color picker
echo.
echo [U] uninstall
echo.
echo [B] go back
set /p "="<nul
for /f "skip=1 delims= eol=" %%$ in ('replace ? . /u /w') do if not defined # set "fz=%%$" & echo(
goto localization_list

:localization_list
if "%fz%"=="" goto localization
if /i "%fz%"=="1" goto localization/mission_titles
if /i "%fz%"=="2" goto localization/colorized_weapon_names_and_categories_check
if /i "%fz%"=="3" goto localization/rainbow_colored_text_in_player_inspect_windows_check
if /i "%fz%"=="4" goto localization/fantazia_related_localization_changes_check
if /i "%fz%"=="5" goto localization/shortcut
if /i "%fz%"=="c" goto localization/color_picker/general
if /i "%fz%"=="u" goto localization/uninstall
if /i "%fz%"=="b" (goto menu) else (goto localization)

:localization/colorized_weapon_names_and_categories_check
if not exist "%apb%\APBGame\Localization\GER\EULA.GER" (goto localization/warning)
findstr /i /c:". colorized weapon names and categories" "%apb%\APBGame\Localization\GER\EULA.GER" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (goto localization/colorized_weapon_names_and_categories) else (goto localization/warning)

:localization/colorized_weapon_names_and_categories
findstr /i /r /c:". colorized weapon names and categories.*\(\+\).*" "%apb%\APBGame\Localization\GER\EULA.GER" >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    del /f /q "%apb%\APBGame\Localization\GER\InventoryItemTypes.GER"
    del /f /q "%apb%\APBGame\Localization\GER\ShopUIFilters.GER"
    echo [92mmodifying: EULA.GER ^(1^)[0m
    powershell -noprofile -command "$apb=(gc config\_temp\path.txt)+'\APBGame\Localization\GER\EULA.GER';$null=new-item -force $apb -value ((gc -encoding utf8 $apb) -replace ('. colorized weapon names and categories.*\(\+\).*','. colorized weapon names and categories') | out-string)"
    goto localization
)
findstr /i /r /c:". colorized weapon names and categories.*\(\+\).*" "%apb%\APBGame\Localization\GER\EULA.GER" >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==1 (
    xcopy /s /y /q "config\_localization variations\colorized weapon names and categories\APBGame" "%apb%\APBGame" >nul
    echo [92mmodifying: EULA.GER ^(1^)[0m
    powershell -noprofile -command "$apb=(gc config\_temp\path.txt)+'\APBGame\Localization\GER\EULA.GER';$null=new-item -force $apb -value ((gc -encoding utf8 $apb) -replace ('. colorized weapon names and categories.*','. colorized weapon names and categories <color:R=0.078 G=1 B=0>(+)<color:/>') | out-string)"
    goto localization
)
```

Comment: I assume it's related to [SuperUser - Why does running PowerShell change my console font?](https://superuser.com/questions/706562/why-does-running-powershell-change-my-console-font)

Comment: @SomethingDark using `chcp 437 > nul` before each powershell command fixed it. Thanks for the hint!